# Intel® TinyCrypt: how to use AES-128/CTR

Tags: c++, c, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to do AES-128/CTR encryption/decryption using [Intel TinyCrypt](https://github.com/01org/tinycrypt) (written in C). I took a look at the test case provided by the library, but still have a few questions on how to use it. Here's the code of the test case (see the complete source code [here](https://github.com/01org/tinycrypt/blob/master/tests/test_ctr_mode.c)):

```cpp
/*
 * NIST SP 800-38a CTR Test for encryption and decryption.
 */
uint32_t test_1_and_2(void)
{
    const uint8_t key[16] = {
        0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88,
        0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c
    };
    uint8_t ctr[16] = {
        0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb,
        0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff
    };
    const uint8_t plaintext[64] = {
        0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96, 0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11,
        0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a, 0xae, 0x2d, 0x8a, 0x57, 0x1e, 0x03, 0xac, 0x9c,
        0x9e, 0xb7, 0x6f, 0xac, 0x45, 0xaf, 0x8e, 0x51, 0x30, 0xc8, 0x1c, 0x46,
        0xa3, 0x5c, 0xe4, 0x11, 0xe5, 0xfb, 0xc1, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x52, 0xef,
        0xf6, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x45, 0xdf, 0x4f, 0x9b, 0x17, 0xad, 0x2b, 0x41, 0x7b,
        0xe6, 0x6c, 0x37, 0x10
    };
    const uint8_t ciphertext[80] = {
        0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb,
        0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff, 0x87, 0x4d, 0x61, 0x91, 0xb6, 0x20, 0xe3, 0x26,
        0x1b, 0xef, 0x68, 0x64, 0x99, 0x0d, 0xb6, 0xce, 0x98, 0x06, 0xf6, 0x6b,
        0x79, 0x70, 0xfd, 0xff, 0x86, 0x17, 0x18, 0x7b, 0xb9, 0xff, 0xfd, 0xff,
        0x5a, 0xe4, 0xdf, 0x3e, 0xdb, 0xd5, 0xd3, 0x5e, 0x5b, 0x4f, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x0d, 0xb0, 0x3e, 0xab, 0x1e, 0x03, 0x1d, 0xda, 0x2f, 0xbe, 0x03, 0xd1,
        0x79, 0x21, 0x70, 0xa0, 0xf3, 0x00, 0x9c, 0xee
    };
    struct tc_aes_key_sched_struct sched;
    uint8_t out[80];
    uint8_t decrypted[64];
    uint32_t result = TC_PASS;

    TC_PRINT("CTR test #1 (encryption SP 800-38a tests):\n");
    (void)tc_aes128_set_encrypt_key(&sched, key);

    (void)memcpy(out, ctr, sizeof(ctr));
    if (tc_ctr_mode(&out[TC_AES_BLOCK_SIZE], sizeof(plaintext),
            plaintext, sizeof(plaintext), ctr, &sched) == 0) {
        TC_ERROR("CTR test #1 (encryption SP 800-38a tests) failed in %s.\n", __func__);
        result = TC_FAIL;
        goto exitTest1;
    }

    result = check_result(1, ciphertext, sizeof(out), out, sizeof(out));
    TC_END_RESULT(result);

    TC_PRINT("CTR test #2 (decryption SP 800-38a tests):\n");
    (void) memcpy(ctr, out, sizeof(ctr));
    if (tc_ctr_mode(decrypted, sizeof(decrypted), &out[TC_AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
            sizeof(decrypted), ctr, &sched) == 0) {
        TC_ERROR("CTR test #2 (decryption SP 800-38a tests) failed in %s.\n", __func__);
        result = TC_FAIL;
        goto exitTest1;
    }

    result = check_result(2, plaintext, sizeof(plaintext),
            decrypted, sizeof(plaintext));

exitTest1:
    TC_END_RESULT(result);
    return result;
}
```

My input data is a double pointer (2D array) and I'd like to keep it that way:

```cpp
uint8_t ** mydata = gen_rand_data(const size_t height, const size_t length);
```

Here's my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. AES-128 is a block cipher, with 128-bit key.
2. CTR mode makes the AES-128 a stream cipher and lets encrypt/decrypt data with arbitrary size.
3. Having AES-128/CTR, the output (ciphertext) has the same length as plaintext.
4. To improve the security, it's better to use 128-bit IV (nonce) for encryption.

Now here's my questions:

1. Can I say `ctr` (initial counter, right?) is our IV?
2. Why the `ciphertext` (expected value) and `out` (calculated value) are 128-bit bigger than `plaintext`?
3. Why the code copies `ctr` value in the beginning of `out`?
4. To encrypt `mydata` (2D array), I just need to loop over it and simple feed bytes from `mydata` to `tc_ctr_mode`, regardless of the dimension of `mydata`. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware of CTR mode, it is absolutely necessary to never use the same key/counter combination twice.

Comment: Why have you chosen to use counter mode?

Comment: @zaph I'm working on a library, so the client has to be worry about it. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @zaph, regarding why CTR, the options provided by TinyCrypt are "CBC", "CCM" and "CTR". The first two are block cipher and need some sort of padding. Do you have any comment?

Comment: The usual mode is CBC with [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). It seems the library does not support padding so you would have to add and remove the padding in your code, that is not difficult. Or choose a library that supports the standard encryption options such as padding. Note: CTR mode is very easy to get wrong, Microsoft has made that mistake in mainline applications a couple of times.

Comment: Another point is to choose an implementation that supports the machine instructions that use the CPU crypto instructions, that can make a significant difference in performance, I have seen up to a 1000 times difference in throughput.

Comment: That sounds scary. Not sure padding is efficient in our case or not. I'd like to not touch the array structure. Meaning receive a 2D array as plain, encrypt it and pass it with same structure (dimensions) to the caller. [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/137916/intel-tinycrypt-aes-128-ctr-to-encryption-decryption-of-2d-arrays)'s my implementation. Would you please take a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure padding adds overhead but it is a small price. For small data the performance cost is in the setup, for large data the padding is insignificant. You are going to have to add a block of data to the encrypted data for the counter or iv in any case.

Comment: The use case involves a lot of small chunks of data encryption/decryption. So the sum of the padding overhead might be significant. Isn't it? The other thing is that I'm still confused why I have to store the counter with encrypted data? Can't I simply store it somewhere else (metadata)?

Comment: Re code review: It is unclear how the counter is created and shared between the encryption and decryption. Since the key/counter combination **must be unique for each encryption** that is a problem. A common method or generation the counter is to make it a combination of a cryptographically secure random byte array and an initial counter value for encryption and to prepend this to the encrypted data. On decryption the counter value is picked off the encrypted data.

Comment: I perfectly understood the requirement. Let's say whoever is going to use the methods is responsible to generate a secure key/counter (satisfying all the requirements), then, is my implementation correct? Thanks.

Comment: For the record, I'm coding it to be used in SGX. Thus it cannot contain any IO operation. The client has to generate key/counter for every attempt of encryption.

Comment: Expecting a user to correctly handle the counter is like building a pedestrian bride without railings and telling the users "Don't fall off", they will of course fall off. No professional engineer would build such a bridge. In general the endpoint we strive for is security, not just encryption, the implementation here provides encryption but not security. Do we as software developers want to be professionals?

Comment: Change your API, have the user provide a cryptography secure random number and key on encryption. Correctly create a counter value using that value. Prepend the counter to the encrypted data. On decryption only have the user supply the key and pickup the counter from the encrypted data. At least that way there is a reasonable chance of correct usage. Also provide a function for the user to use to obtain a cryptographically secure random number (CPRNG).

Comment: It's written before your comment.
You're perfectly right. The thing is, I'm trying to add an extra layer around TinyCrypt to increase the abstraction (I might need to replace TinyCrypt with something else later) and cannot have any IO operation. And for the client part, I'd write a client which handle the process of key/counter generating according to requirement. Is it acceptable now? Thanks.

Comment: If this is a commercial project with substantial users who expect a secure product and reasonably valuable data to the users and/or an attacker hire a cryptographic domain expert to help with the design and review the implementation, that is what I have done in the past. Getting cryptographic security correct is difficult, making one mistake (bug) is all it takes to render the security useless. Typically attacks go unnoticed, the data is either used by the attacker or goes up for sale on the dark web.

Comment: Agree. We will definitely do that in later stage. At the moment it's more of a prototype for performance measurement. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The counter is generally supplied as the iv parameter if there is no specific counter parameter.
2. The output is 16-bytes longer because the counter is prepended, the counter is block sized and AES has a 16-byte block size..
3. The counter value is not secret and is needed for decryption. Since the same key/counter combination can **never be reused** if the key is going to be reused (a common situation) the counter must be unique and thus not pre-shared. The general answer is to pre-pend the counter value to the encrypted data.
4. Yes providing the decryption end knows a priori the array dimensions. But is is probably better to use some form of [marshaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) to preserve the array shape.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to understand #3. So I can skip inserting `ctr` into the beginning of `out` (the client guarantee same key/counter combination is never reused). Is it right?

Comment: Regarding #4, we have to maintain the dimension of array in metadata in a separate storage (I mean this information is known for decryption). Would that be enough?